How is Apache2 choosing which VirtualHost to use?
I have 2 apache sites enabled. The first is the default one 000-default.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

The second one is for my django project:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.example.com
        Redirect 301 / "https://test.example.com"
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName test.example.com
                # logs
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.example.com.error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/test.example.com.access.log combined
                # process
                WSGIDaemonProcess test.example.com python-path=/home/test.example.com python-home=/home/test.example.com/.venv display-name=%{GROUP}
                WSGIProcessGroup test.example.com
                WSGIScriptAlias / /home/test.example.com/config/wsgi.py
                # alias
                Alias /static /home/test.example.com/tmp/static
                Alias /media /home/test.example.com/tmp/media
                # dirs
                <Directory /home/test.example.com/tmp/static>
                        Require all granted
                        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                                ExpiresActive On
                                ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
                        </IfModule>
                </Directory>
                <Directory /home/test.example.com/tmp/media>
                        Require all granted
                        <IfModule mod_expires.c>
                                ExpiresActive On
                                ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
                        </IfModule>
                </Directory>
                <Directory /home/test.example.com/config>
                        <Files wsgi.py>
                                Require all granted
                        </Files>
                </Directory>
                # certbot
                Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

With stystemctl status apache2 everything is fine except for one info that Apache can not determine the fully qualified domain name. Now when I access the ip of the server I get the default Apache page which is fine.
However, if I access for example 123.123.123.123/abc/def it tries to access my Django project.
Why is it trying to do that and how can I avoid it?
If I set a global ServerName it works and just returns a NotFound on the IP/abc/def but I don't understand why. I thought it chooses the most specific VirtualHost and if that one is not available just the first one, which I thought would be the default one in the IP/abc/def case.

There is only one VirtualHost for *:443 so any connection using https will find your Django project.

The problem is not that my django project is found in general. The problem is why is it also found on the ip of the server?

My point is that https://123.123.123.123/abc/def points to your Django project. Are you sure that your browser is using http?

It shows an error that https is not working but will still end up at the django project with a 500 error. But excactly how can i fix it to have https://123.123.123.123/abc/def point to the apache default file or just have apache show a Not Found?
